# How to use fancybox 3 without a tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, fancybox

We are using [fancybox 3](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#introduction) to create a way for site visitors to click on the image and see it display in the lightbox-like format. We have tried the following and can get it to work with only `<a>`, but we want it to work without the `<a>`.

How can we get the fancybox to work without the use of `<a>` tags?

```js
(function($) {
$('.fancybox').fancybox({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="fancybox">
  <figure>
    <a href="myurl/img1.png" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="myurl/img1.png" alt="thumbnail">
    </a>
  <figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="myurl/img2.png" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="myurl/img2.png" alt="thumbnail">
    </a>
  <figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="myurl/img3.png" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="myurl/img3.png" alt="thumbnail">
    </a>
  <figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="myurl/img4.png" data-fancybox="images">
      <img src="myurl/img4.png" alt="thumbnail">
    </a>
  <figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any elements and you can use `data-src` attribute to specify the source, for example, replace this

`<figure>
    <a href="myurl/img1.png" data-fancybox="images">...`

with this

`<figure data-src="myurl/img1.png" data-fancybox="images">...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply use like so

```js
$(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<img src="myurl/img1.png" class="fancybox" data-fancybox="images" data-src="myurl/img1.png" alt="thumbnail">
```

Comment: It would also work without any JS, because you have added `data-fancybox` attribute and default click handler is attached to these elements.